# Href link is not working along with data-revel-modal inside anchor tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

In php href of anchor tag is not working with onclick event where as onclick is working fine

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setData(user_num,user_name,user_query,subject,user_email,user_phone,status,status_change_date,query_date)
    { 
        $("#user_num").val(user_num);
        $("#user_name").val(user_name);
        $("#user_query").val(user_query);
        $("#subject").val(subject);
        $("#user_email").val(user_email);
        $("#user_phone").val(user_phone);
        $("#status").val(status);
        $("#query_date").val(query_date);
        $("#status_change_date").val(status_change_date);
        var date = query_date.split('-');
        var mon = parseInt(date[1]) - 1;
        //alert(mon);
        $("#dob_Month_ID").val(mon).change();
        $("#dob_Day_ID").val(date[2]).change();
        $("#dob_Year_ID").val(date[0]).keyup();
    }
</script>
```

i have fetched all the values and added it to $data and transferring it as parameter to javascript function

```
$query = "select user_num,user_name,user_query,subject,user_email,user_phone,status,query_date,status_change_date from userqueries";
            $result = mysql_query($query,$con);

            if($result && mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
            {
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    list($user_num,$user_name,$user_query,$subject,$user_email,$user_phone,$status,$query_date,$status_change_date ) = $row;
                    $data ="'$user_num','$user_name','$user_query','$subject','$user_email','$user_phone','$status','$status_change_date','$query_date'";
                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row["user_num"] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row["user_name"] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row["user_email"] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row["user_phone"] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row["subject"] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row["user_query"] . '</td>';                 
                    echo '<td>' . $row["status"] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . date('l M d y',strtotime($row["query_date"])) . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . date('l M d y',strtotime($row["status_change_date"])) . '</td>';
                    //echo '<td><a href="viewtitle.php?title_id=' . $row["user_num"]. '"  data-reveal-id="myModal" onclick="setData(' . $data . '); " >Edit  Record</a></td>';                                                              
                    echo '<td><a href="viewuserqueries.php?user_num=' . $row["user_num"] . '"  data-reveal-id="myModal" onclick="setData(\'' . $data . '\'); ">Edit This Record</a></td>';                                                                          
                    echo '<td><a href="adminreply.php?user_num=' . $row["user_num"] . '">Reply user</a></td>';                                                                          



        echo '<td><a href="viewuserqueries.php?user_num=' . $row["user_num"] . '"  data-reveal-id="myModal" onclick="setData(' . $data . '); ">Edit This Record</a></td>';
```

in href i have added url of same page where it is, when i click on Edit this Record  i am able to see mymodal popup screen but not getting the query string in url.

Have used this revel modal
http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/reveal.html

Please help!!

Comment: even if i removed onclick even from achor tag still on chick i am able to see the modal window but the page is not reloading with the query string.

Comment: href is not working.. but if remove  data-reveal-id="myModal" then href works but the no modal window

Comment: If it href works then it will redirect then how can you show model?

Comment: model preventing default events from js

Comment: so whats the solution i want to reload the page with the query string in url and pop up the modal widow showing corresponding values.

Comment: why you want do that? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154978/discussion-between-ahmed-ginani-and-vjain).

Comment: i have a form showing what user has queried , now admin will click on the hyperlink and a model window will pop-up where admin can reply and submit  or if admin want to update the viewed details onclick the data corresponding to the row will be shown as per id passed in url and admin can update from there